# How to get firebase installation auth token in flutter app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-ab-testing

I'm creating Firebase Remote config experiment with A/B testing for my Flutter app. For validating the experiment on test device I need to get `Firebase installation auth token` that associated with each Firebase installation.

How can I get this token in "Flutter-way"? In [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ab-testing/abtest-config#validate_your_experiment_on_a_test_device) there is way to get it for Swift, Kotlin etc.. But not for Dart/Flutter.

In my app I have `firebase_core` package installed and FirebaseOptions has a bunch of ids:

```
this.apiKey,
this.appId,
this.messagingSenderId,
this.projectId,
this.measurementId,
```

But no Firebase **Installation** Auth Token.

Comment: please tell if you found a way to get it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is if you've got the firebase cloud messaging installed as well, getting the token from there. In my app I didn't so I wanted to figure this out myself so I wrote a small package to solve this.

I'm not sure if it works on any type of device as I've only tried it locally on the devices I have (Android and iOS) but using this token you can do the AB testing in firebase console.

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_device_id

Answer (score 0):

[firebase_app
_installations](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_app_installations) is a new Flutter package from the Firebase dev team that I believe will provide you with what you need.